# Trouble loading CyanogenMod using rEFInd manager

Tags: linux, android, pop-os, refind

So, I'm getting this error when using rEFInd and trying to load Android. Here is a picture of the error as displayed.

[image: rEFInd]

The Android entry in `/boot/efi/EFI/refind/refind.conf` is as follows:

```
menuentry Android {
volume cc24a13b-a535-4e82-b250-ed69614c6b86
icon os_android.png
loader cm-x86-14.1-r5/kernel
initrd cm-x86-14.1-r5/initrd.img
options "BOOT_IMAGE=/cm-x86-14.1-r5/kernel root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.selinux=permissive"
}
```

Things to note:

1. Android is installed into a folder on the root of the Linux partition, which is formatted as BTRFS.
2. The distro Linux is installed on is Pop! OS by System76.
3. Android was installed using Alien following the RPM instructions [here](https://www.android-x86.org/releases/releasenote-cm-x86-14-1-r5.html).
4. The laptop in question is from Razer and has an Nvidia GeForce RTX 2080 Max-Q, so some settings may be required to allow it to boot with Nvidia Graphics.
5. When installing using Alien, there was an error related to not being able to add it to GRUB's `custom.conf` file, since I don't have GRUB installed.

Comment: Does CM's kernel even have EFISTUB? Note that refind is different from grub by nature. efi grub's `linux` command does not rely on EFISTUB, while refind really just chainload the linux kernel as an EFI executable, I think. Probably you need a bootloader that supports the "native" / "direct" (sorry I don't know what's the right word for it) linux booting. (As long as that bootloader itself is an EFI executable, you should be able to chainload it with refind if you wish.)

Comment: @TomYan I was able to load Android but am stuck on "Detecting Android x86..."

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. So you talking about refind or what? Because the screenshot you give shows something else.

Comment: I'm talking about refind and Android?